# OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: db.sqlite3 when doing collectstatic on django

Tags: python, django, heroku, collectstatic

I already have done collectstatic before, and it went well.
Now I tried to deploy the app to Heroku, and got the error. It reproduces locally as well.

> OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: '/Users/admin/Desktop/Programming/Python/UkranianFunds/src/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/app/staticfiles/db.sqlite3'

Here is my project structure:
[image]

I have my db.sqlite3 in gitignore if that matters.

Here is my settings:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'static'
]
```

My db.sqlite file is in the src directory. Not clear why collectstatic adds all these subfolders.

Comment: Side note: [you probably don't want to use SQLite on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+sqlite) due to its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

Comment: @Chris thank you. Yeah, I know that, but I just want to run it first. I still have the app in debug mode. Is it the case that the app couldn't be deployed on Heroku properly with sqlite?

Comment: You should be able to deploy it (and the use of SQLite shouldn't cause the problem you're asking about), but the state of the database will frequently and unpredictably reset back to whatever was most recently committed.

Comment: @Chris, understood, thank you. Do you have ideas on where I can look to resolve the issue I described above?

Comment: I'm not sure. Suggest you use a debugger to step through your code and see what value `PROJECT_ROOT` has, etc. My first thought was something recursive, but it seems to terminate since it ends with a filename instead of repeating forever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple - I just deleted my staticfiles folder, and made collectstatic again - and it worked well.